# Injective or surjective function $f(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

I have this exercise:
Show if the next function is injective, surjective or bijective.

$$f \colon \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x,y)= xy. $$

I know the injective function is 1 by 1, i,e. $f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b \quad$ and surjective is a function that maps an element $x$ to every element $y$; that is, for every $y$, there is an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$.

My doubt in the part of $\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I don't know how interpret that. Could you help me with any hint, please?

Comment: Hint 1: Can you find two distinct points $\left( x_1, y_1 \right)$ and $\left( x_2, y_2 \right)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x_1y_1 = x_2y_2$?

Comment: Hint 2: Are all real numbers product of two real numbers?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh for hint 1: How about $(x_{1},y_{1})=(0,1)$ and  $(x_{2},y_{2})=(1,0)$? And for hint 2: Yes, the product between real numer always is a real number.

Answer (score 2):

It is definetly not injective, since $f(1,2)=f(2,1)=2$. More generally, you cannot have an injective map from space $A$ to space $B$ if the dimension of $A$ is higher than the dimension of $B$. Intuitively: you have many more elements in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ than in $\mathbb{R}$.

However, $f$ is surjective: just fix $y=1$ and then for any $z$ the pair $(z,1)$ does the job. Finally, since it is not injective it cannot be bijective.

Comment: " More generally, you cannot have an injective map from space A to space B if the dimension of A is higher than the dimension of B."
I think you also need a smoothness condition to conclude (e.g. the map is constrained to be $C^1$)

Answer (score 2):

The function is surjective, but not injective. Therefore, it is not bijective.

1. For every $x\in \mathbb R$, there exists $(x,1)\in \mathbb R^2$ such that $$f(x,1) = x\cdot 1 = x$$
   so, $f$ is surjective.
2. Take $(x_1,y_1) = (1,6)$ and $(x_2,y_2) = (2,3)$. Then, $(x_1,y_1)\ne (x_2,y_2)$ but $$f(x_1,y_1) = x_1y_1 = 6 = x_2y_2 = f(x_2,y_2)$$
   so, $f$ is not injective.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a doubt. Is it sufficient to find an ordered pair $(x,y)$ that satisfies $(x_{1},y_{1})=(x_{2},y_{2})$ to say that it is not injective?

Comment: No! In that case, you are not involving $f$ at all, so, is every function injective? Certainly not. Note that $f$ is injective if and only if for every $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)\in \Bbb R^2$, $f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_2,y_2)$ implies $(x_1,y_1) = (x_2,y_2)$. The contrapositive tells you that it suffices to find **some** $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)\in \Bbb R^2$ which do not satisfy the property, i.e. we have $(x_1,y_1)\ne (x_2,y_2)$ but $f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_2,y_2)$. Does this make it clearer? @MiguelJV

Comment: Completely clear, thank you. @epsilon-emperor

Answer (score 2):

The wording of the questions suggests you're confused by the $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ part. For any set $X$, the notation $X^2$ represents the Cartesian product of $X$ with itself, or in other words the set of all *pairs* of elements of $X$. In set notation:

$$X^2 = \{(x, y) : x \in X \land y \in X\}$$

So $\mathbb{R}^2$ just means "the set of all pairs of real numbers $(x, y)$". Thus, $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denotes "this function takes two real numbers as input, and produces a single real number as output". Thus the "typical" input of $f$ is a pair of real numbers $(x, y)$, and its "typical" output is a single real number, say $z$.

To check whether $f$ is injective, you need to test whether every output of $f$ is produced by a unique input - in other words, if $f(x_1, y_1) = f(x_2, y_2)$, is it possible to have $(x_1, y_1) \neq (x_2, y_2)$?

Likewise, to check whether $f$ is surjective, you need to test whether every possible output is produced by some input. In other words, given $z \in \mathbb{R}$, can you always find $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x, y) = z$?

Comment: Awesome explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Proceed the same, with your same reasoning. In this case $ f $ is injective if and only if from $ f (x, y) = f (a, b) $ it follows that $ x = a $ and $ y = b $. Then analyze whether or not it is injective. For surjectivity, you would only have to see if each real $ z $ is of the form $ xy $, which certainly does happen ($f (z, 1) = z$).